# C++ Inaccurate Calculation

Tags: c++

I got wrong answer on calculating array of floats.

```
float total =1;
        for(int i= 0; i<16;i++){
            total = total * floats_array[i];
            if(i!=15)
            cout << floats_array[i] << " * ";
            else
                cout << floats_array[i] << " = ";
        }
         cout << total << "\n";
```

#### Compiler answer:

[image]

#### Correct answer:

[image]

I need something like 3 digits right to point.

Any suggetion?

Comment: We need more info, like what type total is and how youre printing it

Comment: @dwcanillas,@Alex K Question updated. I trying to figure out this issue and i print it to file and "cout" command.

Comment: _And how you are printing it_

Comment: And the contents of `floats_array`.

Comment: @4EACH You didn't specify *how* you're printing the number.  That screenshot you posted just didn't come out of thin air.

Comment: also, float has a precision of about 6 digits... so your number would be incorrect anyway.

Comment: provide your code completely...it is not possible to suggest something without going nto details of your code...else if everything is right try using setprecision(int n)  function

Comment: @4EACH Your calculation will be flawed right from the start.  Floating point numbers such as `1.6`, `3.1`, and others in your array *cannot* be represented exactly in binary.  As a matter of fact, most of your numbers in the array cannot be represented exactly in binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, floating-point values are formatted with up to six significant decimal figures. There are manipulators to change this; to get three decimal places, you want

```
#include <iomanip>

std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << total;
```

For me this prints `362955.656`, which you'll note is still imprecise: a typical 32-bit `float` only gives six or seven decimal places of precision. Use `double` for more precision; that gives me `362955.533`, correct to at least three decimal places.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now, how i am assigning it into variable ?

Comment: @4EACH: It's already in a variable. Or do you mean you want a formatted string variable? Use a `stringstream` in the usual manner.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to print up to three decimals?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector< float > floats_array( 16, 1.123 );

    float total = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i<16;i++) {
         total = total * floats_array[i];
    }

    float rounded_total = std::floor( total * 1000 ) / 1000;
    cout << "total           = " << total << endl;
    cout << "total (rounded) = " << rounded_total << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The [output](http://ideone.com/zwTqbi) of which is `total = 6.398` (instead of `total = 6.39847`).

Comment: std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << total;
        float rounded_total = std::floor( total * 1000 ) / 1000;
        cout << "total           = " << total << endl;
        cout << "total (rounded) = " << rounded_total << endl;
if i remove first line rounded_total is wrong answer, How first line effects on the other lines (your suggestion)

Comment: @4EACH Could you please elaborate your comment by updating your question. I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, it looks like the values you print are being converted from a float to int since it is rounding up. I'd check your array type and how you're printing. Its impossible to get into more detail without more code. Provide a better [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better answers from the community.

You can try and override cout with something like

```
cout.precision(15);
cout << float_array[i];
cout << total;
```

This will set cout precision to 15 places. You can change this number to whatever you want.